# Buoyancy versus viscosity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vacuum, buoyancy, viscosity

A common problem in casting is removing the air bubbles that might might be in the mold material, like plaster or resin. This is typically done by degassing--putting the mold material under vacuum to increase the buoyancy of the bubbles which grow larger and rise to the top of the liquid and pop.

There are two schools of thought about how this happens. Some people think the bubble does not rise very much, it just grows in size as the vacuum increases and eventually the bubble gets so big that it touches the upper surface of the liquid and pops. Other people think the bubble becomes more buoyant, eventually begins to rise, then pops when it reaches the surface.

So, we have two basic factors here: the viscosity of the mold material which is preventing the bubble from rising / getting bigger, and the buoyant force of the bubble which is a function of the vacuum in the vacuum chamber.

How can we relate these factors mathematically? For example, let's imagine you had a quart container of resin of a certain viscosity V and wanted to remove all the air bubbles from it within 1 hours time. How much vacuum would be required?